# REST Service, access not allowed on POST

Tags: ajax, rest, post, service

I created a REST service and I'm connecting to it using JQuery ajax and I'm passing and receiving data as JSON. When I'm using GET it works fine but when I'm doing a POST it's not working, It's not even entering debug(service).

It's giving me this error:
*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:23262/GetAllDrawsShort. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:40464' is therefore not allowed access.*

and I'm using the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** which should allow all domains

I found similar issues and tried them but didn't work for me.

Code in Global.asax (Service):

```
    private void EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

    }
```

Service class (Service):

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetAllDrawsShort", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<DrawShortObject> GetAllDrawsShort(string token, Guid userId)
    {
        if (Util.IsAuth(token))
        {
            return new DrawLogic().GetAllDrawsShort(userId);
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

JQuery (Client page):

```
function GetAllDrawsShort() {
    var jData = {};
    jData.token = "123";
    jData.userId = "2f9e15d9-3654-4a43-89f4-07fea98a146f";

    return $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",        
        async: true,
        url: address + "GetAllDrawsShort",
        data: JSON.stringify(jData),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved the problem using jsonp as dataType and responding with a custom callback wrapped response.

First change your ajax request dataType to 'jsonp'.

Then build your service response:

`string callback = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["callback"];
string data = callback + "(" + yourJsonData + ")";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(data);`

Comment: Can you give me an example please